# How to use router-link with event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I want to pass the information to another page.When I was just testing without using route I was able to pass information from one component to anther but when I implemented route like this, It navigating to other component when click event I am not getting information to another page. 
The code is below which has a issue, sorry I cannot post all of the code because of code is too lengthy.
Can anyone help me please?

```
<router-link  @click.native="$emit('viewDetails', model)" to="/modelDetails">
view details
</router-link>
```

Comment: I mean router-link is not firing an event. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both the emission and the navigation to occur, you probably want to use a regular `<a>` and bind it to a method on the component that handles both of these actions:

`<a @click="myFunc(model)">View details</a>`

```js
methods: {
  myFunc(model) {
    this.$emit('viewDetails', model);
    this.$router.push('/modelDetails');
  }
```